# Wrong function type declaration

Tags: haskell

I have the following function that sholud return only odd numbers from the List

```
oddsOnly :: Integral a => [a] -> [a]
oddsOnly [] = []
oddsOnly (x:xs)
 |odd x = x : oddsOnly xs
 |otherwise = oddsOnly xs
```

My question is about the aim of using

> Integral a =>

Actually it is not  posssible to implement such function with such type declaration

> oddsOnly :: [a] -> [a]

As far as I know *even* and *odd* functions are in standart *Prelude* library so why simplified daclaration does not work?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The signature of `odd` and `even` is [**`odd :: Integral a => a -> Bool`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:odd) and [**`even :: Integral a => a -> Bool`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:odd) respectively. So these contain an `Integral a` [type constraint [Haskell-wiki]](https://wiki.haskell.org/Data_declaration_with_constraint).

A type constraint has nothing to do from where it is defined. It specifies that the function only is defined for a subset of types. Only for types that are members of the [**`Integral`** typeclass](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#t:Integral), you can use the function. Integral types are types like that specify a subset of ℤ, so `Int`, `Int64`, `Word8`, `Integer`, … Types. `odd` and `even` do not make much sense over `Float`s, `String`s, `Char`s, etc. What would that mean?

By thus specifying the `Integral a =>` type constraint, you specify that this function can only work with integer-like items.

Note that you can use [**`filter :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [a]`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:filter) here to retain only odd numbers:

```
oddsOnly :: Integral a => [a] -> [a]
oddsOnly = filter odd
```

Answer (score 9):

> why simplified daclaration does not work?

Because you can't tell if a string is odd or not. Or if a float is odd or not. In general, it's not possible to tell if a value of any type `a` is odd or not because the notion of being odd may not be defined for this type.

It *is* defined, however, for `Integral` types, so you must specify that `a` is `Integral`.

In terms of Haskell, `odd` works on `Integral`s only:

```
Prelude> :t odd
odd :: Integral a => a -> Bool
```

Thus, you must pass it a value of a type that is `Integral`.

Answer (score 3):

Let’s look at the type signature of `odd`: `odd :: Integral a => a -> Bool`. So to use `odd` with a parameter, that parameter needs to be `Integral`. This makes sense intuitively: as @ForceBru said in another answer, you can’t tell whether e.g. a float such as `1.5` or a string such as `"hello"` is odd, as the notion of oddness is only defined for integral values.